# Spring Security with Custom Auth Server and Microsoft SSO resulting in double "nonce" parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application running that serves some static html/css/javascript via a rest endpoint(GET).
Now I want to add security to the page so not everyone can access the resources.
For this I am provided with a authorization uri, client id and client secret.
My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-id=${CLIENT_ID}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.provider=custom-provider

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.authorization-uri=https://example.com/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.token-uri=https://example.com/oauth/token
```

When I call localhost:8080 spring returns something like this:

```
https://example.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&scope=openid&state=SOME-STATE-ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&nonce=SOME-NONCE-ID
```

This auth server redirects to

```
https://MICROSOFT-LOGIN-PAGE.com/SOME-MICROSOFT-ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=SOME-MICROSOFT-CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauth/authorize&scope=openid&nonce=SOME-NONCE-ID&nonce=NONCE-ID-FROM-PREVIOUS-REDIRECT&response_type=code&state=-SOME-STATE-ID
```

Then I see the Microsoft login page with the following error:

> AADSTS9000411: The request is not properly formatted. The parameter 'nonce' is duplicated.

Originally I had `https://oauthdebugger.com/debug` as a redirect uri. When I then manually remove the nonce parameter that gets attached from spring everything works as it should and I get redirected to `https://oauthdebugger.com/debug` and I see a SUCCESS message with the state and authorization code.

When I change the redirect uri to `http://localhost:8080/` I again get the error from Microsoft that the parameter nonce is duplicated. Even when I manually remove it.

I would have expected to get redirected back to localhost:8080 and see the html/css/javascript loaded.
Unfortunately I do not have any access/control over this custom authentication server and I have to use it.

This is my first time working with (spring) security and OIDC/oauth2.
Please show me where I got something wrong or point me in a direction.

Thanks in advance